# Nullpointerexception generated with RESTEasy wadl generator

Tags: jboss, resteasy, wadl

RESTEAsy WADL generator was included in our application referring [How to generate wadl file for resteasy in jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475036/how-to-generate-wadl-file-for-resteasy-in-jboss). 
Deployment done in JBoss EAP 6.4 is successful. But on accessing the WADL generation URL http://host:8080/rest-serviceapp/application.xml, it is generating the following error -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlWriter.getStringWriter(ResteasyWadlWriter.java:36)
org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlWriter.getBytes(ResteasyWadlWriter.java:26)
org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServletWriter.writeWadl(ResteasyWadlServletWriter.java:32)
org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServletWriter.writeWadl(ResteasyWadlServletWriter.java:45)
org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet.service(ResteasyWadlServlet.java:55)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

The web.xml we use is -

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<display-name>Restapp_Service</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>    
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy WADL</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/application.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>   
</welcome-file-list>
```

The resteasy-wadl dependency is -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-wadl</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

REST service comsumes/produces JSON. 
Why is the WADL/xml generation ending up in nullpointer exception? What could be the mistake(s) we are making?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Apologies for the 1 year delay. We were unable to solve the problem in JBoss EAP 6.4 later on. Recently we moved to swagger, using the reference [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Wildfly 10.1.0.

I fixed it by using resteasy-wadl 3.0.19 as all other resteasy libraries have this version on Wildfly 10.1.0.

I also had to exclude the resteasy-jaxrs library in the pom, else the resteasy-jaxrs library was included in my war, causing the issue:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-wadl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-wadl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Also, if you use another version than the version of the resteasy libraries already installed in your JBoss, these resteasy libraries (resteasy-jaxrs...) will be installed a second time as dependency of the resteasy-wadl library. These duplicate libraries seem to cause lots of conflicts.